# Limit minimum characters in wordpress themplate default search

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

This is my site's woocommerce product [page](http://cas.ge/?post_type=product) 
As you can see, I use two search: The first above contact menu item and the second one in sidebar. First search is a template default search and the second one is woocommerce product search widget.

My aim is to limit character numbers in both search. I have this code in woocommerce product search widget and it works good. Just try to search with less then 17 characters and you will see what I mean:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="woocommerce-product-search" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/'  ) ); ?>">
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"><?php _e( '', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
<input pattern=".{17,}" required title="17 characters minimum" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search Products&hellip;', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
```

But the same code (after copy/paste) doesn't work for the first search.
This is the first/template default search code:

```
<div class="widget-search">
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( get_home_url() ); ?>/" class="searchform" id="searchform" method="get" role="search">
    <input type="search" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Search...', 'pixar' ); ?>">
    <button type="submit"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </button>
</form>
</div>
```

How to get the same result for the template default search? Simple copy/paste doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to implement this snippet, i hope this code will help

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">
 
<form id="myform">
<label for="field">Required, minimum length 17: </label>
<input type="text" class="" id="" name="field5">
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>
// just for the demos, avoids form submit
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field5: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 17
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

just keep the `id` of form and input field `name` attributes same

Comment: Do yo mean something like this? `<input type="text" minlength="17" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Search...', 'pixar' ); ?>">` Doesn't work

Comment: Exactly this!! I am using this with php html form

Comment: If not working then try JavaScript to handle this stuff

Comment: Exactly this doesn't work/I;m afraid,I'm very poor in javascript

Comment: @Merkucio happy to help you :)